# how to put html page into ext js panel?

Tags: extjs

I want to put some html into ext js panel. I have some panel and using `panel.body.update('html code here')` method. But when the page size is bigger than panel size there is no scrollbars to see whole page. Can I fix it? Or there are other ways to put html in Ext JS components?

Answer (score 0):

Try below :-

```
            {
                xtype : 'panel',
                id : 'agreement-content',
                html : "",
                cls : 'agreement-text'
            }
```

Then  you can set your html in this panel like below.

```
Ext.getCmp('agreement-content').setHtml('Your html content');
```